# Java 2 SDK and Java Tools looking for Packages

Tags: java, eclipse, classpath, package

Say I have a class TreansferBook that is part of org.cadenhead.library package

I read that Java 2 SDK and Java Tools looks for packages in:

1 The org\cadenhead\library subfolder of where the java command was entered

First question is, in Eclipse, where is the option to modify where the java command was entered?

I don't even know how u would do it on the command line; would it be like

C:> cd

Would directory be the workspace and project directory? And are packages in side this direcytory

C:\\ java org\cadenhead\library

2 The org\cadenhead\library subfolder of any folder in your ClassPath setting

I know the classpath tells the jvm where classes and packages are located. Again, as I asked above, is this a subfolder of workspace/project/?

3 The org\cadenhead\library subfolder of a java archive fil (JAR) in your Classpath

Finally, what is this?

Comment: In Eclipse a Java project should already have a root source folder--you don't need to set anything. What is what?

Comment: So packages go in that root directory or do they go in some other directory. And if so, could packages contain classes from different directories in different projects?

Comment: Packages are rooted in any of the project's source directories, and source directories are configured in the project settings. Yes, projects can depend on other projects, but I don't know how granular that can be, e.g., I don't know if you can say "project A depends on classes x, y, z from project B".

Comment: @DaveNewton I didn't mean projects depending on other projects I meant packages from on projects using classes in another project.

Comment: Projects depending on classes from other projects are projects depending on other projects. If it's not another *Eclipse* project then you can import classes from project A into project B, or create an external dependency. Start looking at the project build path and library options; it will be quicker than waiting for people to answer questions here.

Comment: I am still confused. Isnt projects depending on other projects differnent than packages depending on other packages?

Comment: Eclipse organizes things into projects. As I said, I don't know if a project can depend on specific packages in another project--nor *should* you, IMO, because it makes the coupling between the projects brittle. I already told you the mechanism--you can import whatever classes you want if you can find them on the disk. You can depend either on a project (for sure), possibly more granularly within a project, but it'd be easier to break that coupling then.

Answer (score 0):

When using an IDE like eclipse, you don't set anything.  The IDE already knows where your code is and can set the classpath appropriately.  This is not something you need to worry about, it's one of the perks of using an IDE.

Where java is run from is not important.  What is important is that the classpath for the java command is set to contain the root directory of your class files (the parent of /org in your case) and any dependent jar file you may have.

Answer (score 0):

Some things to about class loading and Eclipse:

1. The JVM (and the compiler) look for classes in every directory and in every JAR file listed on the CLASSPATH. For example, if you have a class path like: CLASSPATH=c:\workspace\myproject;some_library.jar, then the VM will look for a class org.cadenhead.library.SomeClass in

   1. c:\workspace\myproject\org\cadenhead\library
   2. In the directory org\cadenhead\library contained in the JAR file.
2. In Eclipse, the default directory on the classpath is the "bin" directory inside your workspace, plus all linked projects and JAR files.
3. The location from which the "java" command was called is the project directory itself.